# List Comprehension with if ,else condition and filling missed value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to create a new field in our existing dataframe with the help of already exist field using if else condition in list comprehension and fill missed by using condition.

Want to fill missed data with 5 and rest with (df_delta['model_trigger']-1)

```py
df_delta['time_periods_st'] = [(model_trigger - 1) if model_trigger != "np.NaN" else 5 for model_trigger in df_delta['model_trigger']]
```

New field with above mentioned name and follow the condition.

Comment: can you show us how `df_delta` looks like ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.where` & `isnull` to check NaN

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_delta = pd.DataFrame({"model_trigger": [np.NaN, 10]})
df_delta['time_periods_st'] = np.where(df_delta['model_trigger'].isnull(), 5, df_delta['model_trigger'] - 1)
print(df_delta)
```

**Output:**

```
   model_trigger  time_periods_st
0            NaN              5.0
1           10.0              9.0
```

Comment: Thank You ! for giving me very fast reply.

Comment: can you please explain me what is wrong with list comprehension using if else condition?

Comment: 1. You need to use either `np.isnan` or `math.isnan` to compare `NaN` values. 2. In pandas you can do most things faster without a for loop.